# How to simultaneously run a same python code but different inputs?

Tags: python

I have a scientific simulation code that do a lot of calculations (solving ODE's) and it takes for a couple of day.

- The code creates a folder that saves output.
- If the created folder is exist, code creates another folder.
- Code reads some initial `.txt` files but does not change them.
- I do not have any setup file or binary file. I basically run the simulation like `python3 runSimulation.py`
- At the end of the running, code removes `__pycache__` and other temp folders.

I want to ask, *If I run the code with some inputs (the `txt` files) and before it finishes, I run code again with another inputs, does this situation occur any discrepancy? Can you suggest another way (or best way or the most pythonic way)?*

When I try to it, I did not see any discrepancy between results, but I want to convince myself. To avoid it, I always make a copy of the code and run it in different location for different inputs.

Comment: That depends on the exact details of your code whether two concurrent instances of it might interfere in some way. We can’t say without seeing the code.

Comment: Every new execution will be a new process. Since there are only read operations, you don't need to worry about race conditions leading to deadlocks either - read locks are shared locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you run your script, a new process is created. So, let's say, you run your program 5 times at the same time: 5 processes will be created. Processes do not share memory/scope with each other. Therefore, they are completely independent and do not affect each other. It is safe to run your program. However, ensure that your code is outputing to different files per process.

EDIT:

To ensure a different file every time a separate process is run, create a random number, or better, uuid and name your folder with this random string.

E.g.

```
import uuid
random_string = str(uuid.uuid4())
my_new_path = '/home/user/my-project/' + random_string + '/output'
```

This way every time you run your script, a new folder/file with a unique name shall be created to which you can output your results.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any advise for this issue? Should I make a setup file/binary file?

Comment: Let me edit my original answer to answer your current question.

Comment: I am sure that all folders/files that I create have different names i.e. different paths. Thanks for further info.